# Algebra: When calculating the variance of Zero-inflated Poisson dist

Tags: variance, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation, calculus

I am deriving the variance of zero-inflated Poisson distribution, whose PMF is
$$
P(X=k) = \begin{cases} \pi + (1-\pi)e^{-\lambda} \; , \; if \; k=0 \\ (1- \pi) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \; , \; if \; k \in \{ 1, 2, \cdots \}
\end{cases}
$$

I am stuck in the place where I need to calculate
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{j=0} (j+1) \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}
$$
It should be something like
$$
e^\lambda (1+\lambda)
$$
but I am not sure how I can derive it.

Comment: Split the sum into two by splitting $(j+1)$ into $j$ and $1.$  The rest should be obvious.

Comment: @whuber OMG! Yeeeeessssss! This is it. I was so stupid... Thanks a lot!!!